# jBPM 6.2 WorkItemHandler - cannot access DataOutput Set

Tags: jbpm

I'm writing a Work Item Handler and whereas the input parameters are obviously supplied, and there is a space to put the results (outgoing parameters), there doesn't seem to be any simple way to access the DataOutputSet which holds the output parameter definitions.

From what I've read, the DefinitionService could be the right approach (which I think is easily available via injection), however, that appears to require the deploymentId as well as processId and taskName in order to access the data sets.

I've worked out how to get the processId from the workItem, and the taskName appears to be automatically supplied as an input parameter, but I cannot see how to access the deploymentId from within a WorkItemHandler.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

PS. I'm a bit of a Java novice too (C# is my normal trade) so please err on the side of more detail rather than less. ;)

Comment: Can you please provide a bit more context (post code) on "but I cannot see how to access the deploymentId from within a WorkItemHandler."

Comment: I'm not really sure what more context I can give. I am trying to access the DataOutputSet so I can get the output parameters definitions.

Comment: I've worked out how to get the DeploymentId, by casting to WorkItemImpl (it's just not available on the interface) but I haven't managed to get the injection of services working, so the question is still open.